# My javascript application I created only works once and then can't be replicated unless I delete the file

Tags: javascript, html

I hope I'm not asking a "duhish" question with what I'm asking but I do need some clarification on what's going on in the "background". I created a simple clock exercise for myself this weekend. It works, it shows up on my browser and shows the current time just like I want it to. That said, when I try to create it again with a different HTML file and Javascript file.... it doesn't work again. It shows up in the original file I created but on the same file that has the same code... It doesn't show the timer.

Here's the HTML I wrote down in the original

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kenneth's clock</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=''>
    <script src='clock.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id ='clock'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the Javascript.

```
function getTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var h = now.getHours();
    var m = now.getMinutes();
    var s = now.getSeconds();

    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    setTimeout('getTime()', 1000);

    function checkTime(time) {
        if(time<10) {
            time = "0" + time;
        }
        return time;
    }

}

window.onload = function() {
    getTime();
}
```

Imagine if I recreated that entire thing again and I changed the id on the new HTML file to digitalclock. I make the new code in javascript to getElementById('digitalclock') and viola.. new exercise to learn basic javascript....

For some reason, it doesn't work. What's going on in the backend to make it so that I can't get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Add the 4 filenames

Comment: please change the setTimeout to this `setTimeout(getTime, 1000);`. don't pass strings to setTimeout and so. It's a bad practice, not flexible and unperformant.

Comment: I assume that on the second call, `clock.js` is already cached, and therefore get's executed before the `p#clock` exists. check out the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead of `window.onload`